# Preloader page animation

Tags: jquery, preloader

I'm looking for a simple example of preloader page animation. What I need is to show a circle (an SVG image), on white background and centered on both axis, that rotates on the Y axis while the page is loading.
I tried to look around the web, but I'm going crazy because there are too much tutorials.

Can any one help me to obtain this purpose?

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-content">Web site content</div>
<div id="loading">
    <div class="loadingDiv">Loading</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.loadingDiv').animate({
         opacity: '1'
    });

    $('.loadingDiv').animate({
        rotation: 720
    }, {
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
        },
        duration: 3000,
        complete: function () {
            $('#loading').fadeOut();
            $('main').fadeIn();
        }
    }, 'easeInOutQuint');
});
```

**SCSS:**

```
#loading {
background: #FFFFFF;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;

.loadingDiv {
    background: #2a2a2a;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 200px;

}
```

}

I'm not sure if this is the correct way because all is triggered after *document.ready*...

Here you can see the [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rxxf6kge/).

Comment: This one looks easy http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/07/simple-jquery-preloader-css-image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actual loading as loading aninmation is used to mask the actual web content loading . Jquery document ready runs when DOM is ready.

You need to stop animation when web content is ready so add this

```
$(window).ready(function(){
     $('#loading').fadeOut();
     $('main').fadeIn();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rxxf6kge/3/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your solution works perrfectly! However, is this the way used in the other sites, like those in themeforest? I knew that the preloader animation works during the loading page process and not on page loaded . Am I wrong?